# Why are some apps keep running in OS X even if I quit them?

Tags: macos, ms-office, skype, applications

At least three apps are now doing the following:

- In its menu, I click on quit
- It starts quiting but
- then never finish quiting.

I can switch to it. The icon in the dock bar shows it is running. The menu is there, but the Quit option is disabled.

What's going on?

It is happening with:
- Microsoft Word
- Skype
- Another one, not by Microsoft

After an update, Word is not doing it anymore. It is puzzling.

Answer (score -3):

It is due to bugs. Most likely in those programs, or in the OS X system. Essentially the program never completes the "Quit" action, so it doesn't exit and thus stays running.

Another cause could be hardware error - such as a non-responding hard drive. If that was the case, you would be seeing problems everywhere and not just with the Quit menu option in a few programs.

If you want to investigate the specific cause on your machine, I would suggest using dtruss to see what system calls the application makes as you hit quit. It could for example be hanging waiting for a mutex/semaphore, or similar - suggesting a deadlock or livelock. In other words, a bug.

Comment: If it was "bugs" then everybody would see them. As they don't, it's the least likely explanation.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that everybody would see them - that's flawed logic. A bug can be triggered by a certain state that is not universal. hectorpal's setup could have something that triggers the bug on his machine, while most others wouldn't see the bug as they haven't got the same triggers on their machine. So it could still be bugs...

Comment: I agree with @Tetsujin. I'll investigate using dtruss though

Comment: What explanation do you have beside a software bug or a hardware error? I'm just interested, as I see no other logical explanation. User error? ;-)